# Limits and Continuity invlolving Trigonometry

Tags: limits, trigonometry

Evaluate the follwing limits,

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{tan(x)}{x}$

$Hint$ : $tan(x) \frac{sin(x)}{cos(x)}$

Comment: Isn't $\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ ?

Comment: Yeah, i followed the tutorial question, without actually checking it, my bad sorry, edited it anyway

Comment: Another hint: Limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}$ is equal to ...?

Comment: @alans i'm out of ideas brother,

Comment: the limit alan refers to is $1$ and you can prove it with LHopital also.

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{tan(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\frac{1}{\cos{x}}=1\times \frac{1}{\cos{0}}=1\times 1=1$

Comment: @CarryonSmiling You could, but (as argued many times) it's highly circular. Using L'Hopital for that amounts to differentiating $\sin$, to get what is by definition the derivative of $\sin$ at $0$...

Comment: oh wow, you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan(x)}{x}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x\cos{x}}$

Applying LHopital this is equal to:

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{cos(x)}{-x\sin(x)+cos(x)}=\frac{1}{0+1}=1$